# why cant i connect my phone to pc via usb i was able to do it before

Tags: usb, connection-issues, windows

I have a moto e 1st gen android phone and it used to get connected to my pc every time btw i hv win 7 32 bit but now nothing happens on connecting 
There is no notification on phone but it still keeps charging and also there is no prompt on pc also there is nothing in the device manager
I tried different usb cables i got my usb point change on the phone i manually installed the drivers nothing wrks

Comment: Is it charging?

Comment: Is usb debugging on in developer options?

Comment: Yes its charging and yes i tried debugging

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running kitkat, try the following on the phone.

1. Go to settings > Storage
2. Click the 3-dot [or usb icon] button on the top right corner
3. Select Media device [MTP]
4. Try connecting again

PS: Have you tried connecting to another PC?

Comment: Yes i tried both of em

Comment: Try connecting your phone to the PC after going to recovery mode.